# Календарь для Datepicker

Tags: javascript

Всем привет. Делаю календарь для Datepicker. Есть функция, которая создает таблицу и заполняет ее числами конкретного месяца. Но проблема в том, что если привязать ее к select на событие onchange то она создает при каждом изменении новую таблицу(что неудивительно). Как сделать что бы эта функция 1 раз создавала таблицу, а потом только обновляла ее. Заранее спасибо.

```js
var nowDate = new Date();
  var today = nowDate.getDate();
  var currentMonth = nowDate.getMonth();
  var currentYear = nowDate.getFullYear();
  var temp = new Date(currentYear, currentMonth , 0);
  var lastDay = temp.getDate();
  monthList.value = currentMonth;
  yearList.value = currentYear;

 
  function changeTable(currentYear, currentMonth){
   var d = new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, 1);
    var t = d.getDay() - 1;
    if(t < 0){
     t = 6;
    }
    var a = 0;
    while(d.getMonth() == currentMonth){
     var tr = document.createElement('tr');
     var i = 0;
     while(i < 7){
      var td = document.createElement('td');
      if(a == 0 && i < t || d.getMonth() != currentMonth){
       td.innerHTML = '';
      }else{
       td.innerHTML = d.getDate();
       d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
      }
      tr.appendChild(td);
      i++;
     }
     document.getElementById('t').appendChild(tr);
     a++;
   }

  }
```

Comment: При выполнении вашего скрипта возникает ошибка: {
  "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: monthList is not defined",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 19,
  "colno": 3
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте создать массивы, в которые будете записывать значение, а если переменная undefined, то создавать новое:

```js
var nowDate = new Date();
var today = nowDate.getDate();
var currentMonth = nowDate.getMonth();
var currentYear = nowDate.getFullYear();
var temp = new Date(currentYear, currentMonth , 0);
var lastDay = temp.getDate();
//monthList.value = currentMonth;
//yearList.value = currentYear;

var tElement=document.createElement('table');
document.body.appendChild(tElement);
var trs=[],tds=[];


function changeTable(currentYear, currentMonth)
{
    var d = new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, 1);
    var t = d.getDay() - 1;
    if(t < 0)
        t = 6;
    var a = 0;
    while(d.getMonth() === currentMonth || a<trs.length)
    {
        if(trs[a]===undefined)
            trs[a]=document.createElement('tr');
        var i = 0;
        while(i < 7)
        {
            if(tds[a*7+i]===undefined)
                tds[a*7+i]=document.createElement('td');
      if(a == 0 && i < t || d.getMonth() != currentMonth)
          tds[a*7+i].innerHTML = '';
            else
            {
                if(String(d.getDate()).length==1)
                    tds[a*7+i].innerHTML = d.getDate();
                else tds[a*7+i].innerHTML = d.getDate();
                tds[a*7+i].style="text-align: right";
                d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
      }
            trs[a].appendChild(tds[a*7+i]);
            i++;
        }
        //document.getElementById('t').appendChild(trs[a]);
        tElement.appendChild(trs[a]);
        a++;
 }
}
changeTable(currentYear,currentMonth);

var addMonthBtn=document.createElement('button');
document.body.appendChild(addMonthBtn);
addMonthBtn.textContent="Add month";

addMonthBtn.onclick=function()
{
    while(nowDate.getMonth() === currentMonth)
        nowDate.setDate(nowDate.getDate() + 1);
    currentYear=nowDate.getFullYear();
    currentMonth=nowDate.getMonth();
    changeTable(currentYear,currentMonth);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло